# Completely remove a div when user navigates back to the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a website where let us say we have an index.html with 2 divs.

```
<div id="top">
    Some Content
</div>
<div id="content">
    Some Content
    <a href="page.html"></a>
</div>
```

The content id div has an anchor tag. When I click on anchor tag,page.html loads in the same tab. Now when I press back button of browser, I want that div with id should not be present.
Actually, I just want that when someone visits the website for first time, the div top should appear and then should never appear again even if some one follows a link and tries to go back. Although, when someone again opens the website in a new tab, the website should come all over again (with the top div and the same thing again). Is it possible?

Comment: I guess you should go for a server-side solution. Have a look at sessions and cookies an choose the one that suits best.

Comment: It's possible, but only by doing some form of session management (most easily by setting a cookie or localStorage token on first visit, and hiding the div on page load if that cookie or token is present.)  This can be client-side javascript, doesn't have to involve the server.

Comment: Oh, except for this part: "Although, when someone again opens the website in a new tab, the website should come all over again with the top div"   In that case, the answer is no, not possible (you can't reliably detect whether the user got to your page via the back button or otherwise.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with JavaScript, but it's probably better done server-side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <script>
    var content, body;
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        content = document.getElementById("content");
        body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        if (localStorage.getItem("wasHere") !== null) {
            body.removeChild(content);
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("wasHere", "true");
        }
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="top">
      Some Content
  </div>
  <div id="content">
      <!-- You need to put text inside links for them to show -->
      <a href="page.html">Some Content</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with this solution is that `localStorage` is easily modifiable and not reliable. Thus, again, you should really use a server-side solution. This is there if you need it, though.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Can I destroy localStorage when the person refreshes the website or opens it in a new tab? I think that's not possible.

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible to sense _how_ someone leaves a webpage, but only when. Sorry.